# Call a function with hash parameter

Tags: ruby

I defined some functions like this:

```
def func1(hash)
    hash.each do |key, value|
       puts "#{key}, #{value}"
    end
end
```

I can call the function like this:

1. `func1({somekey: "somevalue"})`
2. `func1(somekey: "somevalue")`
3. `func1 somekey: "somevalue"`

but this format does not work:

- `func1 {somekey: "somevalue"}`

Please explain this.

Comment: The Ruby parser interprets your hash as a block, just like `each { ... }`

Comment: oh.... thank you @Stefan, i perfectly understand after reading your answer

Comment: BTW, yet another way to call the method is `func1 **{somekey: "somevalue"}` – the `**` operator converts the hash to keyword arguments.

Comment: @Stefan You can just pass a plain old Hash to methods expecting keyword arguments. No need to splat it again.

Comment: @HolgerJust yes, if you do provide parentheses. I just wanted to show a way to pass a hash literal without them.

Answer (score 1):

Using curly braces `{}` seperated by a space is how you declare a block in ruby, so there is a conflict here in the parsing step. Ruby thinks you're passing the method a block.

For example, this is a block being passed to the `select` method:

```
[1, 2, 3].select { |x| x >= 2 } # => [2, 3]
```

You can call it an "inline" block and it's an alternative to using `do..end` (with slight differences).
It's better in my opinion to stick to using the parenthesis here `()`

```
func1({somekey: "somevalue"})
```

Comment: _"it's syntactical sugar for using do..end"_ – not quite, `{ ... }` has higher precedence.